# Why on youtube a 1080p video looks better than 720p ? (My screen max resolution is 720p)

Tags: video, display, youtube, graphics, video-encoding

A resolution greater than 720p looks better on my 720p screen . I want a clear and basic answere to understand this.

Comment: 1080 > 720. More data equals better quality. Scaled down video will be sharper because of the larger size becoming smaller. Try this. Find a crappy image online that is large. Than resize it to 1/2 of the size. The image will suddenly look better because scaling down averages things away.

Comment: FWIW, it appears the close votes are on the grounds this is opinion based.   I don't believe it is [ and I've provided an answer which is fact based to it ], and would urge that this not be closed for that reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a video is uploaded to Youtube, Youtube compress it to make it easier to deliver.   Unfortunately, by its nature this compression reduces quality.  (By way of example I looked at sizes of a high res video on youtube.  The same video encoded at 1080p was 168MB, while only 97.4MB at 720p.

If you have the right tools, you will be able to see that a 1080p video on Youtube is substantially larger then the 720p one.    This means that more detail is being provided in the video stream, thus (even though limited by the number of pixels of your display) there is more date, allowing for a better image.

Another probable factor is that your screen is NOT 720p.  Most "low res" laptop screens would be 1366x768 - which is bigger then the 1280x720 of 720p.  Thus, in full screen mode, your 720p video is being upscaled and loosing quality, while the 1080p video is being downscaled, so can provide more clarity.

Lastly (and I imagine **much less likely**), its possible that the 720p and 1080p video are encoded with different codecs - with your processor being able to offload processing for the 1080p version but require the CPU to handle the 720p version - and struggling to keep up with it.

Comment: I think that's not the entire story. Older uploads 720p _used to_ look quite good on 1366x768 screens, almost indistinguishable from 1080p – it's the newer ones that are incredibly compressed. (Sometimes they miss so much detail that several times I also thought I was watching 480p!) In some videos, YouTube has even stopped showing the "HD" indicator next to the 720p option, and I think I've seen ffprobe actually shows some new videos having a lower 720p H.264 bitrate than 480p H.264 used to be.